# Memory Leak when using Librdkafka to send messages to a kafka server

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, librdkafka

I am setting up a C application that is supposed to send sensor data to a kafka server. The message consists of only a JSON string containing all the sensor names and their values.

The kafka producer is set up like this:

```
int setupKafkaProducer(struct KafkaParameters *kafkaParameters, struct ClientOPCEndpointInfo* *clientInfos, int clientInfosLength, bool runTest)
{
    logInfo("START - Setting up kafka producer", true);

    conf = rd_kafka_conf_new();

    rd_kafka_conf_set_dr_msg_cb(conf, dr_msg_cb);

    rd_kafka_conf_res_t res = RD_KAFKA_CONF_OK;

    // setting up parameters ...

    if (res != RD_KAFKA_CONF_OK)
    {
        g_error("Failed to setup kafka config: %s", errstr);
        logError("Failed to setup kafka config", true);

        return 1;
    }    

    producer = rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER, conf, errstr, sizeof(errstr));

    if (!producer)
    {
        g_error("Failed to create new producer: %s", errstr);
        logError("Failed to create new producer!", true);

        return 1;
    }

    conf = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

The message callback is only used to report possible errors when sending kafka messages.

The messages are sent like this:

```
int sendKafkaMessage(char *kafkaMessage)
{
    int message_count = 1;
    const char *topic = kafkaTopic;
    const char *value = kafkaMessage;

    for (int i = 0; i < message_count; i++)
    {
        size_t value_len = strlen(value);

        rd_kafka_resp_err_t err;

        err = rd_kafka_producev(producer,
                                RD_KAFKA_V_TOPIC(topic),
                                RD_KAFKA_V_MSGFLAGS(RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_COPY),
                                RD_KAFKA_V_KEY(NULL, 0),
                                RD_KAFKA_V_VALUE((void*)value, value_len),
                                RD_KAFKA_V_OPAQUE(NULL),
                                RD_KAFKA_V_END);

        if (err != RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR)
        {
            // g_warning("Failed to produce to topic %s: %s", topic, rd_kafka_err2str(err));
            // logError("Failed to produce topic!", true);

            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // g_message("Produced event to topic %s: value = %12s", topic, value);
        }

        rd_kafka_poll(producer, 0);
    }

    // g_message("Flushing final messages..");
    rd_kafka_flush(producer, 100);

    if (rd_kafka_outq_len(producer) > 0)
    {
        // g_warning("%d message(s) were not delivered", rd_kafka_outq_len(producer));
        // logError("Kafka message(s) were not delivered!", true);

        return 1;
    }

    // g_message("%d events were produced to topic %s.", message_count, topic);

    return 0;
}
```

I suspected a memory leak since the program gets killed by Ubuntu after a certain while.
Valgrind reports the following:

```
==19032== 92,178 bytes in 9 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 45 of 45
==19032==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19032==    by 0x4A37F15: ??? (in /home/.../build/libs/librdkafka.so.1)
==19032==    by 0x49FC06A: ??? (in /home/.../build/libs/librdkafka.so.1)
==19032==    by 0x49E48E3: ??? (in /home/.../build/libs/librdkafka.so.1)
==19032==    by 0x49F0B59: ??? (in /home/.../build/libs/librdkafka.so.1)
==19032==    by 0x49F0F79: ??? (in /home/.../build/libs/librdkafka.so.1)
==19032==    by 0x49B0D67: ??? (in /home/.../build/libs/librdkafka.so.1)
==19032==    by 0x4DC7934: start_thread (pthread_create.c:439)
==19032==    by 0x4E58BF3: clone (clone.S:100)
```

This seems to be an internal problem in the librdkafka library. But I can't tell if it is caused by incorrecty use on my end or by a bug in the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

For the leak reports to be meaningful your application needs to terminate cleanly.

That means not being killed, just a clean exit from `main()`.

Comment: The application is meant to be running indefinitely though. It DOES clean up the producer after it is terminated by an interrupt. And the lost memory increases the longer the program had been running before that.

Comment: If your program is terminating cleanly then you need debug symbols for librdkafka.so.1 se see more clearly where the leaks are.